# Too slow vs Too Long difference

Tags: grammar

Can one say,

> you’re taking too slow?

when referring to them going slow or would one say,

> you’re taking too long.

Answer (score 1):

"You are too slow!" or "You're taking too long!" (or You take too long! You usually need some kind of "object" with take (I guess implicitly, too long a time there), because it's a transitive verb.

Sometimes we use a "dummy" object, as in I'm kicking back and taking it easy, but "I'm taking it slow / slowly" isn't idiomatic unless "it" is contextually defined (some difficult task that you're engaged with, perhaps). (comment by FF)

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure how to "explain" the difference. Is it to do with ***too slow*** being adverbial, where ***too long*** is adjectival? Those two roles clearly lead to different meanings in *He talks too **slow**!* and *He talks too **long**!* But whereas ***to take*** pretty much *has* to have an object, even if it's a "dummy" like *Take it easy*,  ***to talk*** only takes an object in certain relatively unusual contexts like *He talks **rubbish*** and *He talks **a good talk***. So I don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

For the grammatical point of view, I agree with the comment/answer from FumbleFingers. Please refer to that.

I just want to point out the difference in the meaning of **too slow** and **too long**.

If an action is not fast enough to satisfy to, you say it is too slow.

If an action takes longer than expected, you say it is too long.

Both attributes can occur in the same situation. So, you can use any choice of the two.

I have seen both options being used interchangeably but this is my take on it. I really think the meaning of these words only have some overlapping area but not all.

Comment: We don't say that the _action_ is too long, but the time it takes to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You 'take' a period of time (ten minutes, an hour)  to do something; if you are doing it slowly, that period can be described as *too long.* You don't 'take' the speed with which you are doing it.